# Unable to move uploaded files with php (Apache 2.4) - Permission denied

Tags: php, apache-2.4, permissions

In my project I can't use `move_uploaded_file` PHP function because of:

```
Notice:  PHP Request Startup: file created in the system's temporary directory in Unknown on line 0
Warning:  move_uploaded_file(../Pictures/1n0): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/backend/Controllers/News.controller.php on line 114
move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move "/tmp/phpSPAnSj" to "../Pictures/1n0" in /var/www/backend/Controllers/News.controller.php on line 114
```

I tried to fix this problem by changing owner of `/var/www/backend/Pictures` directory and permissions of this dir:

`# ls -la /var/www/backend`:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 10 root   root 4096 Oct 14 20:26 .
drwxr-xr-x.  8 root   root 4096 Oct 18 12:18 ..
...
drwxr-xr-x.  2 nobody root 4096 Oct 13 14:45 Pictures
```

and also, I saw the permissions of `/tmp` dir:

`# ls -la /`:

```
drwxr-xr-x.  19 root root  4096 Oct 16 14:43 .
drwxr-xr-x.  19 root root  4096 Oct 16 14:43 ..
...
drwxrwxrwt.  14 root root   280 Oct 18 12:28 tmp
```

(I tried to change the directory of temp uploads by modifing `php.ini`: `upload_tmp_dir = /var/www/tmp_upload` but apache still keeps tmp files in `/tmp` directory.)

So how can I give permissions to apache for moving temporary uploaded files?

Comment: What user is the PHP scripts running as? `nobody`?

Comment: Im not sure. I saw this user in another forum and I tried to change the owner to this.

Comment: The first step is probably to figure out what user it *actually* is, and set correct owner. However, Serverfault is *probably* not the correct site for this.

Comment: which forum do you recommend for this? `stackOverflow`?

Comment: I'd suggest either superuser.com or unix.stackexchange.com. It's not about development, so StackOverflow is *not* the correct one. Serverfault is geared towards professionals, and we generally require that people understand their setups.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean "Sever fault is geared towards professionals". isn't my problem about server? how do you define "SERVER"?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what OS this is running on. If it were RHEL/Rocky/Alma/Debian/Ubuntu/Suse then MAC might be a consideration.

```
drwxr-xr-x.  2 nobody root 4096 Oct 13 14:45 Pictures
```

Your PHP is running as "nobody"? That's rather unusual - You should really be using a dedicated service account for your webserver - nobody is a service account but already has specific use-cases and semantics that don't quite fit here.

You error can mean that the permissions are wrong. But it it suggests that you're not moving it to a directory named "Pictures" you are trying to move it to a FILE named "..\Pictures\1n0" in the current directory (wrong slashes).

Comment: Im using Linux Fedora. I fixed the wrong slashes but nothing changed.

Comment: Check the SELinux config - you need an exception for this path.

Comment: Explain more please.

Comment: If you don't know how SELinux works then turn it off (`setenforce 0`) wait 5 minutes (this is not documented) test again, then turn it back on (`setenforce 1`). If it works with SElinux off, then you have a lot of work to do learning how to configure and maintain SELinux.

Comment: Use `getenforce` to find the initial state.

Comment: Wow it works! but what happened just now?

Comment: Learn how to manage SELinux - a quick fix would be to set SELinux to permissive, regression test your site then run audit2allow to generate the required policy and apply this.  See https://jfearn.fedorapeople.org/fdocs/en-US/Fedora/20/html/Security_Guide/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Fixing_Problems-Allowing_Access_audit2allow.html